# is there a way to restrict user to input only numerical values for the variables?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main(void)
{   
    int n1,n2,r; // variables

    //this just simply add n1 and n2 and shows the result, i want it
    // to only allow numbers not alphabet
    printf("Enter the first number = ");
    scanf("%d",& n1);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Enter the second number = ");
    scanf("%d",& n2);
    fflush(stdin);
    r=n1+n2;
    printf("total = %d ", r);
}
```

as you can see my codes wont restrict anything, i want help in restricting the input of alphabets

Comment: Read strings and then check that the string only contains digits.

Comment: can you guys give me a hand in this really quick ? cause i need to submit this before saturday :\

Comment: can you show an example? or edit mine!

Comment: possible duplicate of [validating numerical user input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211656/validating-numerical-user-input)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the below question answers yours. Let me know if this helps!

It is using a `while loop` to ensure the input is only numbers, but could easily bee altered to be only `chars`. Also you can set your variable to be only numbers such as `double` or `integer`, the same way you can make it only a `string`.

**Original Answered Link:**
[How to make cin take only numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828937/how-to-make-cin-to-take-only-numbers)

> From Jesse Good's Answer

I would use `std::getline` and `std::string` to read the whole line and then only break out of the loop when you can convert the entire line to a double.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::string line;
    double d;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
    {
        std::stringstream ss(line);
        if (ss >> d)
        {
            if (ss.eof())
            {   // Success
                break;
            }
        }
        std::cout << "Error!" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Finally: " << d << std::endl;
}
```

Hope this helps!